# How to handle longs actions in a mongodb cursor.each?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a `.each()` loop and global variables that are updated in each loop. In each loop there is a `collection.find`, and node.js doesn't wait for the search to finish and goes to the next element before the `find` even gets the first result and that's problematic. I don't think it's the right thing to do to make it wait, I want to deal with it "the node way" (tell me if I shouldn't)

Here is a simplified version of my code :

(It would find all clients that are exactly 50 years old, and do something with the shop in their city)

```
var clients = db.collection('clients');
var current;
var clientnumber=0;

clients.find({"age":50},function(err,results){
    results.each(function(err,client){
        if(client){
            clientnumber++;
            var city = client.city;
            shops.find({"_id":city},function(err,resCursor){
                resCursor.toArray(function(err,bson){
                    //does stuff using the city, client number variables and data from "shop"
                    //including another find and each operation
                });
            });
            clientnumber++;
        }
    }
});
```

(`clientnumber` is not an id, it just counts how many 50 year old clients there are)

When I run this code, the `each` loop is way too fast for the `find` so variables like `clientnumber` and `city` are not up to date when the `find` callback is called. What should I do here ?

I was thinking having an array for cities, something like `cities[clientnumber]=city`, but I don't know how to keep track of `clientnumer`. I thought passing variables locally, like `var currentcity=city;` but I can't be sure it'll be done before going to the next client, and I don't want to have to do it for each nesting.

How do I keep track of my global variables ? You can comment on the structure but it's very simplified so it might not be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over client in sequence. Wait the end of each before starting the next.

```
clients.find({"age":50},function(err,results){
    doclient(clientnumber, 0, results.length, results, function(result){
        // alldone, clientnumber in result
     })
})


function doclient(clientnumber, done, todo, results, callback)
{
    if(done >= todo)
    {
        return callback(clientnumber);
    }
    else
    {
        var client = results[done];
        if(client){
            clientnumber++;
            var city = client.city;
            shops.find({"_id":city},function(err,resCursor){
                resCursor.toArray(function(err,bson){
                    //does stuff using the city, client number variables and data from "shop"
                    //including another find and each operation

                    // call next client
                    setImmediate(doclient, clientnumber, ++done, todo, results, callback);
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // call next client
            setImmediate(doclient, clientnumber, ++done, todo, results, callback);
        }
    }
}
```